# Characterization of invertibility of bounded linear operator between Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator from the Hilbert space $H_1$ to a Hilbert space $H_2$. I've shown that the existence of a $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
\langle T^{*}Tx,x\rangle\ge \delta \|x\|^2 
$$
for all $x\in H_1$, and
$$
\langle TT^{*}y,y\rangle\ge \delta \|y\|^2 
$$
for all $y \in H_2$, implies that $T$ is invertible. But I'm still trying to show the converse, and I'd appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Try to prove the following:

(1) If $T$ is invertible then so is $T^*$ and $(T^*)^{-1} = (T^{-1})^*$.

(2) If $T$ is invertible, then $T^{-1}$ is a bounded linear operator (Open Mapping Theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hint and for mentioning the open mapping theorem.

Comment: your welcome!!!:)

Comment: Actually, if such $\delta$ exists, then it is easily seen that $T$ and $T^{*}$ are injective, but could you please help me see why $T$ is bijective (in which case it would be invertible by the Open Mapping Theorem)?